# MySQL Inserts record with NULL value in NOT NULL column

Tags: mysql

Why does the first INSERT go through for table2.  Note that table2.col_1 is NOT NULL. It doesn't insert NULL for col_1, but mysteriously converts the NULL value to an empty string.  I am using MySQL Version 5.5.28.  Thanks

```
mysql> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table1, table2;

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)   

mysql> CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table1 (
    -> id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
    -> col_1 VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
    -> col_2 VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
    -> PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
    -> ENGINE = InnoDB;

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE table2 LIKE table1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO table1 (id, col_1, col_2) VALUES (NULL, "xxx","yyy");
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO table2 (id, col_1, col_2) SELECT NULL, NULL, col_2 FROM table1 WHERE id=1;
Query OK, 1 row affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
Records: 1  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 1

mysql> SHOW WARNINGS;
+---------+------+-------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                       |
+---------+------+-------------------------------+
| Warning | 1048 | Column 'col_1' cannot be null |
+---------+------+-------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM table2;
+----+-------+-------+
| id | col_1 | col_2 |
+----+-------+-------+
|  1 |       | yyy   |
+----+-------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO table2 (id, col_1, col_2) VALUES( NULL, NULL, "zzz");
ERROR 1048 (23000): Column 'col_1' cannot be null

mysql> SELECT * FROM table2;
+----+-------+-------+
| id | col_1 | col_2 |
+----+-------+-------+
|  1 |       | yyy   |
+----+-------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: maybe it inserts `NULL` string and not the null (*nothing*)

Comment: Strange, I'm doing the same and I do get the nulls inserted... Maybe you could specify PDO::PARAM_INT when you bind the value?

Comment: @JW  Please explain.  I just edited the original post to show how it only inserts a row if the INSERT is fed by a SELECT.

Comment: @Sebas.  Does it insert NULL, or an empty string?

Comment: null, but see my edition of my previous comment

Comment: @Sebas.  See the very bottom of my original post.  Note that there was a warning, but I currently don't know how to see the warning.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL ignores the NOT NULL constraint](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2503712/mysql-ignores-the-not-null-constraint)

Comment: see the link, I think you'll find an answer there

Comment: @Sebas.  Yes, you are correct.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have MySQL's STRICT mode OFF.
Turn it on and you'll get an error.

Otherwise you can test for those warnings with PDO via: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php

Comment: Thanks David,  My bad, turns out to have nothing to do with PDO or PHP.  I edited the original post to show this.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @user1032531 Updated this answer to reflect my further comprehension.

Comment: I bet you are right!  I never knew of MySQL STRICT mode, and will test it out.  Thanks

Answer (score 8):

This behavior is well documented in MySQL docs . [MySQL doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/constraint-invalid-data.html)

If you are not using strict mode, then whenever you insert an “incorrect” value into a column, `such as a NULL into a NOT NULL column` or a too-large numeric value into a numeric column, MySQL sets the column to the “best possible value” instead of producing an error:,but the warning count is incremented

Answer (score -1):

I have tried setting MySQL's STRICT mode OFF and didn't work for me (I even changed it to "my.ini" ).

What worked for me was a `BEFORE INSERT TRIGGER`

Basically you do:

```
CREATE TRIGGER triggerName BEFORE INSERT ON customer
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    if new.`customerName` = '' then
    signal sqlstate '45000'
    SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Customer Name Cannot be Empty!';
    end if;
END
```

In the `MESSAGE_TEXT` you can add whatever text you want the error to show.

Hope it helps!

Most of it found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2514292/2160507)

Comment: I am clearly saying in the start of my post "I have **tried** setting MySQL's STRICT mode OFF **and didn't work**". I am not saying this is the solution.

Comment: What did you mean by "didn't work"? The actual problem of the asker is because his STRICT mode is OFF. So why would you say setting it OFF didn't work when what you need to do is to actually turn it ON?