# MySQL column set to NOT NULL but still allowing NULL values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have every column set to `NOT NULL` but for some reason I am still able to add a `NULL` value in each column. Here is my table info (create syntax):

```sql
CREATE TABLE `addresses` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `address` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    `city` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    `state` varchar(4) NOT NULL,
    `zip` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4545 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Here is a sample `INSERT` that works:

```
INSERT INTO `addresses` (`street`, `city`, `state`, `zip`) VALUES ('', '', '', '');
```

Any ideas as to why this is happening?

Comment: Add insert and select queries also and output

Comment: what the NULL looks like? is it really a null?

Comment: Check this out . . . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15905420/mysql-inserts-record-with-null-value-in-not-null-column.

Comment: Updated question with an insert

Comment: Those are not NULLs but valid empty strings

Comment: Oh I see, well then how can I throw an error for empty values? Is that possible?

Comment: @peterm i am thinking the same thing...

Comment: @doitlikejustin you can use stored procedure and raise an error

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are inserting empty strings, and empty string are not `NULL`, to check for `NULL` error do:

```
INSERT INTO `addresses` (`street`, `city`, `state`, `zip`) VALUES (NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

and you will see error. The `NOT NULL` checks only for values that are not `NULL`.

To prevent empty string either you have to use [triggers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/triggers.html), or do the checks on server side programming language to convert empty strings to `NULL` before performing `INSERT` query.
An example trigger for `INSERT` may be like: (this is just an example)

```
CREATE TRIGGER avoid_empty
    BEFORE INSERT ON addresses
        FOR EACH ROW
        BEGIN
        IF street = '' THEN SET street = NULL END IF;
END;
```

Comment: I see. That does throw an error but can I prevent empty values?

Answer (score 2):

try below

```
INSERT INTO `addresses` (`street`, `city`, `state`, `zip`) VALUES (NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

above will not work

```
INSERT INTO `addresses` (`street`, `city`, `state`, `zip`) VALUES ('', '', '', '');
```

above insert empty string

The empty string specifically means that the value was set to be empty; null means that the value was not set.

to prevent insert empty string check this SO question

[I'm looking for a constraint to prevent the insert of an empty string in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2514178/im-looking-for-a-constraint-to-prevent-the-insert-of-an-empty-string-in-mysql)

Comment: Can I prevent empty values?

Answer (score 1):

`''` isn't `NULL`, `NULL` is `NULL`

This will fail:

```
INSERT INTO `addresses` (`street`, `city`, `state`, `zip`) VALUES (NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

Comment: Can I prevent empty values?

Comment: You could use a trigger like @Sudhir has done above. I'm not sure if you can do a constraint like that. The other option is to validate it in the code that is generating the insert statement.

Answer (score 1):

If you have control over all of inserts to the table then you can either check for empty strings in your client code, or if you want MySQL to return an error you can wrap inserting values in `NULLIF()` function. Assuming that you use php your INSERT statement may look like

```
INSERT INTO addresses(city, address, state, zip) 
VALUES (NULLIF(:address, ''), NULLIF(:city, ''), NULLIF(:state, ''), NULLIF(:zip, ''));
```

Another way to prevent empty strings from being inserted is to use `BEFORE INSERT` trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER tg_bi_addresses
BEFORE INSERT ON addresses
FOR EACH ROW
  SET NEW.address = 
      CASE WHEN 
       CHAR_LENGTH(NEW.address) = 0 OR
       CHAR_LENGTH(NEW.city)    = 0 OR
       CHAR_LENGTH(NEW.state)   = 0 OR
       CHAR_LENGTH(NEW.zip)     = 0 THEN NULL
       ELSE NEW.address
      END;
```

The idea is to detect an empty string and violate `NOT NULL` constraint on one of the fields. If you are using MySQL 5.5 or higher you can use `SIGNAL`.

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d0c86/1)** demo. Try to uncomment last insert statement and the trigger won't allow it to succeed.

Answer (score 0):

Use virtual field, add restriction on it

```
CREATE TABLE `table` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `c1` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `c2` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_not_null` int(11) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (coalesce(`c1`,`c2`)) VIRTUAL NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

Warning, seems MariaDb is not suitable to use (NOT NULL) on virtuals

Comment: hi, please could you edit your answer to explain in more detail? thank you in advance