# Insert on MariaDb fails when ommitting non-default fields

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb

Table Structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `setup_int` (
    `key` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `val` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`key`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
```

As you can see the fields are `NOT NULL`-Fields and have no default value.

We updated to MariaDB 10.1.21 and have the following issue now:
The following query fails without any error message!

```
INSERT INTO `setup_int` (`key`) VALUES ('test');
```

The reason seems to be the missing default value.

- If I add an default value to the table, the insert is successfull.
- If I change the `NOT NULL` to `NULL`, the insert is successfull.
- IF I do it on MariaDB 10.1.20, the insert is successfull.
- If I do the insert with both fields the insert is successfull.

This works:

```
INSERT INTO `setup_int` (`key`,`val`) VALUES ('test',0);
```

The question is: What can I do (some setting, or something else) to make mariadb 10.1.21 to handle this situation like before. I cannot alter all tables right now and i cannot downgrade right now.

The main issue is that the query executed by PHP returns `true` although the insert failed!

Comment: I fail to see what the problem is here. If you setup a table and tell it that `val` cannot be NULL then you have to provide a value for `val` on every insert. So if you cannot provide that value remove the `NOT NULL` or add a DEFAULT

Comment: @RiggsFolly I agree, this behavior seems normal and expected.

Comment: If leaving `val` empty worked in 10.1.20 then there must have been a bug in 10.1.20, so reverting will mean you can ever again upgrade the database

Comment: Yes ist is correct, I agree, but it is not the same behaviour as before.

Comment: Please show the missing PHP code. Which API you use, PDO, MySQLi,...

Comment: This may explain that 10.1.20 had a bug in this area https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-11698

Comment: _The question is: What can I do (some setting, or something else) to make mariadb 10.1.21 to handle this situation like before._ You are asking us how to reapply a bug! You are going to have to fix all your tables as you do not want this bug re-applied

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yes, I am asking this. I am not happy with this. And it is just a quick fix. I will change the table structure as fast as possible. But I searched for solution which is aplicable for lot of customers and lot of tables quickly.

Comment: @RiggsFolly But can you confirm that the failed query should return a query-error message instead not being executed and not throwing an error. This seems to be a another bug.

Comment: Well that depends on your PHP code, and whether you are actually checking for an error or just ignoring it.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I am not talking about an php error but about an mysql-error. There is no error or warning when trying to insert via console directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2503938/1973205

And then you can set the variables like this: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/sql-mode/

As a pure logic fact, it's correct that the query fails.

Comment: Thanks for this. But I think there is no Mode-Value for the given behaviour. As I think you wrote the closest answer to my question i will accept it. It seems to be the case that i have to update all my table structures right now. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you set a constraint that the value of `val` must not be `NULL` and it fails because you try to set it `NULL`.

(`0` is not the same as `NULL`.)

The default value is set during `CREATE`:

```
CREATE TABLE `setup_int` (
    `key` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `val` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    PRIMARY KEY (`key`)
)
```

Comment: Yes, I know this. But that wasn't the question. The question was: what else can i do to make it working but changing the stucture of my tables.